# Cut and paste a line with an exact match using sed

Tags: shell, unix, sed, paste, cut

I have a text file (~8 GB). Lets call this file A. File A has about 100,000 lines with 19 words and integers separated by a space. I need to cut several lines from file A and paste them into a new file (file B). The lines should be deleted from file A. The lines to be cut from file A should have an exact matching string.
I then need to repeat this several times, removing lines from file A with a different matching string every time. Each time, file A is getting smaller.
I can do this using "sed" but using two commands, like this:

```
# Finding lines in file A with matching string and copying those lines to file B
sed -ne '/\<matchingString\>/ p' file A > file B

#Again finding the lines in file A with matching string and deleting those lines,
#writing a tmp file to hold the lines that were not deleted.
sed '/\<matchingString\>/d'file A > tmp

# Replacing file A with the tmp file.
mv tmp file A
```

Here is an example of files A and B. I want to extract all lines containing hg15
File A:

```
ID pos frac xp mf ...
23 43210 0.1 2 hg15...
...
...

File B:
23 43210 0.1 2 hg15...
```

I´m fairly new to writing shell scripts and using all the Unix tools, but I feel I should be able to do this more elegantly and faster. Can anyone please guide me along to improving this script. I don´t specifically need to use "sed". I have been searching the web and stackoverflow without finding a solution to this exact problem. I´m using RedHat and bash.
Thanks.

Comment: Can you post some example data of input and expected output? Makes our lives so much easier when we don't need to guess :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 's|.*|/\\<&\\>/{w fileB\nd}|' matchingString_file | sed -i.bak -f - fileA
```

This makes a sed script from the matching strings that writes the matching lines to fileB and deletes them from fileA.

N.B. a backup of fileA is made too.

To make a different file for each exact word match use:

```
sed 's|.*|/\\<&\\>/{w "&.txt"\nd}|' matchingString_file | sed -i.bak -f - fileA
```

Comment: Could you please explain a bit what this code does in steps. There is one thing I didn´t make clear. I need to write a different fileB for every exact matching word.

Comment: This solution works nicely and is a bit faster than my own script.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use `grep` for this but besides this small improvement this is probably the fastest way to do it already, even if this means to apply the regexp to each line twice:

```
grep '<matchingString>' A > B
grep -v '<matchingString>' A > tmp
mv tmp A
```

The next approach would be to read the file line by line, check the line, and write it depending on the check either to `B` or to `tmp`.  (And `mv tmp A` again in the end.)  But there is no standard Unix tool which does this (AFAIK), and doing it in shell will probably reduce performance massively:

```
while IFS='' read line
do
    if expr "$line" : '<matchingString>' >/dev/null
    then
        echo "$line" 1>&3
    else
        echo "$line"
    fi > B 3> tmp
done < A
```

You could try to do this using Python (or similar scripting languages):

```
import re
with open('B', 'w') as b:
  with open('tmp', 'w') as tmp:
    with open('A') as a:
      for line in a:
        if re.match(r'<matchingString>', line):
          b.write(line)
        else:
          tmp.write(line)
os.rename('tmp', 'A')
```

But this is a little out of scope here (not shell anymore).

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will help you...

```
cat File A | while read line     
do        

    #Finding lines in file A wit matching string and copying those lines to file B
    sed -ne '/\<matchingString\>/ p' file A >> file B

    #Again finding the lines in file A with matching string and deleting those lines  
    #writing a tmp file to hold the lines that were not deleted     
    sed '/\<matchingString\>/d'file A >> tmp

done

#once you are done with greping and copy pasting Replacing file A with the tmp file    
`mv tmp file A`
```

PS: I'm appending to the file B since we are greping in a loop when the match pattern found.